# Select the sql server with the formula calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the data on my table.

[image]

and then I want to get a report like the image below,.

[image]

for flag_approve, if column 1 = approve and if 0 = non_approved. Thank you. If anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pivoting by using aggregation.

Assuming the flag_approve can only be 1 or 0, you can do this:

```
selct school,
    count(*) as total_count,
    sum(flag_approve) as approved,
    sum(1 - flag_approve) as not_approved
from your_table
group by school;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `GROUP BY SCHOOL` and calculate your columns like: 
`counter` is a simple `COUNT(*)` 
`approve` is a `SUM` of `flag_approve` 
`non_approve` is a `SUM` of all rows which have `flag_approve = 0`

```
   SELECT school 
         ,COUNT(*) AS ctr
         ,SUM(flag_approve = 1) AS approve
         ,SUM(IIF(flag_approve = 0, 1, 0)) AS non_approve
     FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY school
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run below command:

---

```
  select school, 
         count(school) as count, 
         sum(flag_aprove) approve, 
         sum(case 
               when flag_aprove = 0 then 
                 1 
               else 
                 0 
             end) non_approved 
    from tes 
group by school
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Can you please add some explanation regarding what the code is doing?